# Laravel: Action not defined

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having this error occur:

> Route [/update] not defined. (View: C:\Server\nginx-1.13.1\html\developer\resources\views\profile.blade.php)"

For this route:

```
Route::post('/update', 'ProfileController@update');
```

and this view:

```
<form class=card method=POST action={{ route('/update') }}>
```

Comment: The `route` helper is for [named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes).

Answer (score 2):

the route() method takes the name not the path

```
Route::post('/update', ['as' => 'my-update', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@update']);
```

then call `route('my-update')`

Comment: I've added more info.  Sorry my initial post was so brief.

Answer (score 0):

or you can just change `route` to `url` or `asset` like this

```
 <form class=card method=POST action={{ url('/update') }}>
```

Comment: I would advocate for named routes instead.  It really helps when you want to re-organize an api.  In this solution, I actually don't even see the point of using {{ ... }} and url().  It's probably more flexible to just put action='/update'

Answer (score 0):

in your web.php , you should give name to your route , then you can access that route by name in blade

```
Route::post('/update', 'ProfileController@update')->name('update');
```

in your blade template

```
<form class=card method=POST action={{ route('update') }}>
```